# How to check which is greater: a**b or b**a for big numbers?

Tags: python, exponentiation

Say I have two numbers, `a` and `b`such that

```
1 <= a, b <= 10**9
```

How can I quickly check which is greater: `a^b` or `b^a`? Calculating `a**b` directly in Python is too slow.

Comment: Compare `a * log(b) = log(b**a)` to `b * log(a) = log(a**b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a mathematical question than a Python related question, but you can use `math.log` to find the `b * math.log(a)` and `a * math.log(b)` and compare them.

```
import math
a = 10
b = 9

if b * math.log(a) > a * math.log(b):
   print("a^b is greater than b^a")
else if b * math.log(a)< a * math.log(b):
   print("a^b is smaller than b^a")
```

Comment: But why I can compare in this way?

Answer (score 3):

If `a,b > e` then you can only compare a,b:

Consider: 
`f(x) = x/ln x`:

Then:

`f'(x) = (ln(x)-1) / ln(x)^2` which is positive for `x>e`: so ***f is increasing for x>e***.

Now if a,b>e:

if `a>b <=> f(a) > f(b) <=> alog(b) > blog(a)`

Same for `a<b`.